# Avoid multiple function member call on an instance in C++

Tags: c++, logging, static-assert

I wrote a logger class for my program but I want to force the client to use my class in a specific way. Here is my `Logger` class:

```
#ifndef __LOGGER_HPP
#define __LOGGER_HPP

#include <Uncopyable.hpp>
#include <sstream>

enum LoggerLevel
{
    ERROR,
    WARNING,
    INFO,
    DEBUG,
    ALL
};

class Logger : private Uncopyable
{
    private:

        static LoggerLevel reportingLevel;
        static std::ostringstream os;
        static bool hide;
        static std::string file;

        LoggerLevel messageLevel;
        std::string className;

    public:

        static void setVerbosity(LoggerLevel level);
        static void setLogFile(const std::string &file);
        static void hideOutput();
        static bool outputHidden();
        static std::ostringstream &getStream();

        Logger(const std::string &className);
        ~Logger();
        std::ostringstream &debug();
        std::ostringstream &info();
        std::ostringstream &warning();
        std::ostringstream &error();
};

#endif // __LOGGER_HPP
```

the implementation:

```
#include <Logger.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

LoggerLevel Logger::reportingLevel = LoggerLevel::ALL;
ostringstream Logger::os;
string Logger::file;
bool Logger::hide = false;

Logger::Logger(const string &className) :
    className(className)
{
    os.str("");
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    os << endl;

    if (this->messageLevel <= reportingLevel)
    {
        if (!hide)
        {
            if (this->messageLevel == LoggerLevel::ERROR)
            {
                cerr << os.str() << flush;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << os.str() << flush;
            }
        }

        if (!file.empty())
        {
            time_t now = time(nullptr);
            string time(ctime(&now));
            ofstream log(file, ios::in | ios::app);
            log << time.substr(0, time.length() - 1) << " " << os.str() << flush;
            log.close();
        }
    }
}

void Logger::setVerbosity(LoggerLevel level)
{
    Logger::reportingLevel = level;
}

void Logger::setLogFile(const string &file)
{
    Logger::file = file;
}

void Logger::hideOutput()
{
    Logger::hide = true;
}

bool Logger::outputHidden()
{
    return hide;
}

ostringstream &Logger::getStream()
{
    return os;
}

ostringstream &Logger::debug()
{
    os << "[DEBUG] " << this->className << ": ";
    this->messageLevel = LoggerLevel::DEBUG;
    return os;
}

ostringstream &Logger::info()
{
    os << "[INFO] " << this->className << ": ";
    this->messageLevel = LoggerLevel::INFO;
    return os;
}

ostringstream &Logger::warning()
{
    os << "[WARNING] " << this->className << ": ";
    this->messageLevel = LoggerLevel::WARNING;
    return os;
}

ostringstream &Logger::error()
{
    os << "[ERROR] " << this->className << ": ";
    this->messageLevel = LoggerLevel::ERROR;
    return os;
}
```

As you can see, I want to force the client to use the class like this:

```
Logger("MyCLass").debug() << "This is a debug message.";
```

So I'd like to statically avoid this kind of use:

```
Logger myLogger("MyClass");
myLogger.debug() << "This is a debug message.";
myLogger.info() << "This is an information.";
```

Is there any solution to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't, these codes are more or less equivalent, besides your wanted form is working on a temporary instance. Why do want to force this actually? Sounds like a XY-Problem for me.

Comment: Since your `debug()`, `info()`, etc. functions are non `const` won't that prohibit to call them from a temporary already? Does that stuff compile?

Comment: Yes of course it compiles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution, thanks to C++11.  You want to rvalue-reference-qualify each of your logging functions:

```cpp
std::ostringstream &debug() &&;
// etc.
```

In otherwords, the `&&` at the end of the function declaration means that  `debug()` and friends can be called only on temporary `Logger` objects:

```cpp
Logger("MyClass").debug() << "foo"; // fine

Logger log("MyClass");
log.debug() << "bar"; // compile-time error!
```

Comment: OK thanks. Unfortunately, this doesnt compile with my compiler (gcc version 4.7.3) :/

Comment: gcc 4.7.3 should have c++11 support.  Have you tried compiling with the -std=c++11 flag?

Comment: Yes, I always use this flag (I do use C++11 API). For this line in my .hpp: `std::ostringstream &debug() &&;` I get this error: `Logger.hpp:106: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration`

Comment: Looks like a couple issues going on.  First, your compiler is too old to support this. :(  I tested with gcc 4.8.2 and I didn't have problems.  Secondly, you won't be able to return a static  `std::ostringstream` member.  But you should be able to remove the `static` off of the member, upgrade to a new version of gcc, and be good to go.

Comment: OK, this is not that easy. I'm cross-compiling using Buildroot toolchain so I'll have to recompile all my embedded OS. I'll compile using gcc 4.8.x and I'll see. Thanks again :)